# Tooltip inside a scrollable component

Tags: html, css, scroll, tooltip

I have a scrollable div . Inside the div I have multiple cards. One of the cards has a tooltip on it. I want the tooltip to be displayed in full on hover , not partially. How can i do it?

Tried with overflow hidden also, not working. Is there a way to put a tooltip in a scrollable component?

```css
.card {
  width: 250px;
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.cardContainer {
  display: flex;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.hoverArea {
  background-color: yellow;
  max-width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.hoverPopup {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 180px;
  min-height: 180px;
  background-color: red;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.hoverArea:hover .hoverPopup {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>
  Hello World
</p>
<div class="cardContainer">
  <div class="card">
    <p>
    Card1
    </p>
    <div class="hoverArea">
      <div class="hoverPopup">
        <p>
        Hey There
        </p>
      </div>
      <p>
      Hover Here
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>
    Card2
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>
    Card3
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>
    Card4
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/0VFNdpm

Comment: Yes something like that , but i want it in the top side. Can you please share the your code.

Comment: do you need the parent block to increase the height when hovering?

Comment: no . i dont want the parent block to increase the height when hovering

Answer (score 0):

The popup can't be shown outside the parent by default, and since you don't want the parent to increase in height, another solution will be needed.

I have added a new element (<div class="tooltip">) to the html like this:

```js
const
    cardContainer = document.querySelector('.cardContainer'),
    hoverArea = document.querySelectorAll('.hoverArea'),
    tooltip = document.createElement('div');

tooltip.className = 'tooltip';
document.body.appendChild(tooltip);

hoverArea.forEach(o => {
    // Show the tooltip
    o.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        tooltip.innerHTML = o.querySelector('.hoverPopup').innerHTML;
        tooltip.style.left = `${o.offsetLeft - cardContainer.scrollLeft}px`;
        tooltip.style.top = `${o.offsetTop + 25}px`;
        tooltip.style.display = 'block';
    });
    // Hide to tooltip
    o.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        tooltip.style.display = 'none';
    });
});
```

```css
.card {
    width: 250px;
    min-width: 250px;
    min-height: 40px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.cardContainer {
    display: flex;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.hoverArea {
    background-color: yellow;
    max-width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.hoverPopup {
    display: none;
}

.tooltip {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 180px;
    min-width: 180px;
    padding: 8px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>
        Hello World
    </p>
    <div class="cardContainer">
        <div class="card">
            <p>
                Card1
            </p>
            <div class="hoverArea">
                <div class="hoverPopup">
                    <p>
                        Hey There Card1
                    </p>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Hover Here
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <p>
                Card2
            </p>
            <div class="hoverArea">
                <div class="hoverPopup">
                    <p>
                        Hey There Card2
                    </p>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Hover Here
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <p>
                Card3
            </p>
            <div class="hoverArea">
                <div class="hoverPopup">
                    <p>
                        Hey There Card3
                    </p>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Hover Here
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <p>
                Card4
            </p>
            <div class="hoverArea">
                <div class="hoverPopup">
                    <p>
                        Hey There Card4
                    </p>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Hover Here
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works in all use cases except one when the user hovers and scrolls at the same time, the popup does not gets scrolled. But this is a very minor case and can be resolved by closing the popup on any scroll event.