# How to make absolute positioned tooltip overlap scrollable container?

Tags: html, css, tooltip, absolute

I have a scrollable container with elements. For each element I want tooltip positioned relative to the element. I want tooltip to overlap the container.

Problem is when tooltip is displayed near the edge of container it widens the space inside container. I'd like to make tooltip overlap the container. How can I achieve that?

Example:
https://codepen.io/tys404/pen/gOLNJXZ

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  left: 20px;
  border: 3px solid pink;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="relative">
    <div class="txt"> blabla </div>
    <div class="absolute"> tooooooltip </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add the tooltip to a higher level such as the body, or better yet use a library such as [tippy.js](https://github.com/atomiks/tippyjs)

Comment: Maybe this could solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66382585/tooltip-inside-a-scrollable-component/66403611#66403611

Answer (score 1):

I changed positioning of tooltip to `fixed` and assigned `x` and `y` position of `div` rect to tooltip style

Comment: Is there a CSS way to achieve it?